# Chart.js not working in Community Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community-builder

In a lightning component inside a Community Builder page, I'm following this guide from the docs exactly: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm

In the community builder view, the chart renders as it should.  However, when I publish and view the community page, I'm getting a failure on the last line in the controller method:

[image: My console output]

I checked and the static resource is loading correctly - and debugging is telling me there's an issue with this line:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that on my community page, I needed to "Empty Cache and Reload".  Not sure why - but that resolved my issue.